# Camel CXF configure WS-Adressing - ReplyTo and MessageID

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf

I need to configure my CxfEndpoint in Camel for WS-Addressing.
My CxfEndpoint Service gets called and sends back a confirmation message.
I need to add/configure ReplyTo, RelatesTo and MessageID fields to the message.

This is how it should look like:

```
<a:MessageID u:Id="_4">169</a:MessageID> 
<a:ReplyTo u:Id="_5"> 
   <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
```

I have set up the CxfEndpoint in camel as such:

```
CxfEndpoint cxfEndpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
cxfEndpoint.setAddress("http://0.0.0.0:8888/service");
cxfEndpoint.setWsdlURL("Service.wsdl");
cxfEndpoint.setCamelContext(camelContext); 
....
```

I added WS-Addressing simply by adding the following:

```
<cxf:features>
  <wsa:addressing/>     
</cxf:features>
```

I could not find any information how to add WS-Addressing configuration to camel cxf. I saw [cxf documentation ws-a](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-addressing.html) but it eludes me how to add the mentioned AddressingProperties maps to a camel CxfEndpoint.
What is the preferred way to configure WS-Addressing for Camel CxfEndpoint? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will close this question for now, because I think I misunderstood the problem and need to investigate this further.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution? I am also facing the problem of how to set CXF SOAP Addressing MessageID in Apache Camel.